# New To Python, Do Not know how to use float

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am a high school student who has just been introduced to python through school. Just for fun, I made a simple program for finding the point of intersection of two y=mx=b formulas. However, unless I put decimal points after the inputs, it rounds the output of the program. I have tried some things using floats but I don't fully understand it. Here is the code:

```
print("When inputting numbers, please make sure to add two decimal points at     the end to make sure answer is not rounded")
x_one=input("Slope of line 1:  ")
y_one=input("Y intercept line 1:  ")
x_two=input("Slope of line 2:  ")
y_two=input("Y intercept 2:  ")
eliminator_1=(x_one*x_two)
eliminator_2=(y_one*x_two)
eliminator_3=(y_two*x_two)
eliminator_4=(y_two*x_one)
print(eliminator_1, eliminator_2, eliminator_3, eliminator_4)
formula_ypro=(eliminator_2-eliminator_4)
formula_y=formula_ypro/(x_two-x_one)
print(formula_y)
formula_x=((formula_y-y_one)/x_one)
print("the point of intersection is", formula_x, formula_y)
h=input("Press Enter To Exit")
```

I am using python 2.7.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.x will (by default) perform integer division when supplied with two integer operands:

```
>>> 4 / 3
1
```

Python 3.x, on the other hand, will perform floating-point division:

```
>>> 4 / 3
1.3333333333333333
```

You can coerce an operand into a float by casting it, forcing floating-point division in Python 2.x:

```
>>> float(4) / 3
1.3333333333333333
```

Python 3.x can still perform integer division, but it uses a new operator:

```
>>> 4 // 3
1
```

Comment: I guess the other piece of the puzzle is that `input` will return an integer or a float depending upon whether you include a decimal point.

Comment: Use of `input` is generally discouraged since it interprets the input as Python code, rather than as a string. `raw_input` should be used instead.

Comment: Note that you can vote to close extremely common duplicate questions such as this one. This helps to reduce fragmentation on the site and make things easier to find.